# Line appears after animating UILabel

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel, drawrect

I am performing 2 animations on MyUILabel.
MyUILable is my custome class derived from UILabel and have implemented 
drawRect method which draws borders only.

This is my animation code:

```
- (void)animateLableIn
{
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f delay:0.0 options:options animations:^{

        label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self animateLableOut];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)animateLableOut
{
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f delay:0.0 options:options animations:^{

        label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
        }
    }];
}
```

At the start of the first animation a grey line appears on the top edge of my label and persists after all animations are finished. 
I want to mention that this line isn't part of my drawRect implementation and it appears even if my drawRect is empty.
Also the label is a bit smaller then it was initially.

Images attached are not proportional.

Before animations:

[image: Before animations]

After animations:

[image: After animations]

Any guess why could that happen?

Comment: I had a similar problem and was to use decimals. The font had trouble to render. Play a lil with the 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the problem.
I have changed the frame of that label at the time the animations was running.
Doing changes to the frame of  the label after the animations are finished fixed the problem.